# Bash array append - removes existing elements

Tags: bash, array, echo

I tried:

```
$ a=("-f" "apple" "c")
$ a+=("-e" "banana" "d")
$ echo "${a[@]}"
-f apple c -e banana d
```

```bsh
$ a=("-e" "apple" "c")
$ a+=("-e" "banana" "d")
$ echo "${a[@]}"
apple c -e banana d
```

Can someone explain why the second output is not `-e apple c -e banana d` (why is `-e` missing)?

Comment: what do you get with `a+=("-f" "apple" "c")`?

Comment: `$ a=("-f" "apple" "c");`
`$ a+=("-f" "apple" "c");`
`$ echo "${a[@]}";`
`-f apple c -f apple c`

Comment: For a definitive view of the genuine contents of a Bash variable, use the built-in command `declare -p a`.